# Vertica/SQL, Case When Syntax

Tags: sql, syntax, syntax-error, case, vertica

I cannot seem to find the documentation for vertica case when syntax.
Can someone help with this,

```
case when S.name = 'Stack' then E.Price end case when M.Type = 'Pricing' then V.value * V.Rate end as "Price"
```

I am getting syntax error.

Comment: This was on the first google search https://www.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/LanguageElements/Expressions/CASEExpressions.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's just one `case` in the beginning and one `end` at the end, and a series of `when`-`then`s between them:

```
CASE WHEN S.name = 'Stack'   THEN E.Price 
     WHEN M.Type = 'Pricing' THEN V.value * V.Rate 
END AS "Price"
```

Comment: is there a way to exclude the null values?

Comment: @excelguy what `null` values? What would you want to do with them?

Comment: perhaps ill open another question for this, but my distinct in my statement is still giving me duplicates in some columns,

Comment: @excelguy yes, please open another question on that, it seem unrelated to this one.

Comment: any idea if "CASE" is exclusive? meaning if one case is matched it won't evaluate the next

Comment: @EliasGhali yes. The first term that is matched retrurns its `then` clause, and the others aren't evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how to use "case"

```
case 
    when S.name = 'Stack' then E.Price  
    when M.Type = 'Pricing' then V.value * V.Rate   
end as Price
```

Comment: is there a way to exclude the null values?

Comment: Could you clarify, which NULL values you want to exclude ?

Comment: Hey eugene, thanks, Perhaps ill open a new question for this. I have a distinct at the beggining of my statement, but some following columns still have duplicates.